# Add new bar button in Navigation Bar with a Tab Bar Controller Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, navigationbar, navigationcontroller

I have the next structure in swift 3:

Navigation Controller -> Tab Bar Controller -> 4 View Controllers

I have 3 commons bar buttons items.
My problem is, in just one of the view Controllers I want to add new bar button item on the top-right corner. This way when I navigate to the others views the new button should not appear.

How can I solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Perfect I solved it. My problem now is that I have a logout button and now It doesn't work.
My structure now is:

UINavigationController -> LoginView -> UITabBarController -> UINavigationControllers in each tab.

I have a Logout button in the last navigationController's header and I want it to go back to the LoginView.

Comment: In loginView you should present your UITabBarController modally and when pressing logout you simply have to call the dismissViewcontroller method.

Answer (score 4):

You should set it with **tabBarController** like this in **Swift**:

```
let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
button.setImage(UIImage(named: "imageName"), for: .normal)
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
let leftButtonBar = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
tabBarController?.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [leftButtonBar].
```

this is best answer forever and works correctly.

Comment: I spent hours looking for this solution. Works perfect, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can have the below structure by which you can have individual 
 navigation to add button for each view controller

```
Tab Bar Controller ->Navigation Controller -> 1st View Controllers
                    ->Navigation Controller -> 2nd View Controllers
                    ->Navigation Controller -> 3rd View Controllers
                    ->Navigation Controller -> 4th View Controllers
```

Comment: when i follow you answer it is working fine but when I push from 1st View Controllers ,how tabbar is showing and when i add button in the vc with y axis = 0 , the navigation bar is hiding the button , how to solve this.